# How to get the retrieve firebase values to display on TextInput and update details react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the values from firebase-database and set the values to display on the TextInput, so users can edit the values there and press the button to update the values back to firebase. I have tried all the ways but it still not working, is there anyone can help me to solve this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal,
  TextInput,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions}from 'react-native-router-flux';
import firebase from './firebase';

export default class RecipeDetails extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      text: '',
      ingText:'',
      stepsText:'',
      modalVisible: false
    }

    this.vegeRef = this.getRef().child('Vegetarian');   
  }

  setModalVisible(visible){
    this.setState({modalVisible:visible});
  }

  getRef(){
    return firebase.database().ref();
  }

  getVegeItems(vegeRef){

    vegeRef.on('value',(snap) =>{
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        vegeRef.push({title: child.val().title}),
        vegeRef.push({ing:child.val().ing}),
        vegeRef.push({steps:child.val().steps}),
        vegeRef.push({_key:child.key})
      });
      this.setState({
        text: this.state.text(title)
      });
    });
  }

  updateItem(){
    this.setModalVisible(true);

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Modal
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                animationType={'slide'}
                onRequestClose={() => {}}
            >
            <Text>Edit the details and Update.</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="Add Recipes"
                    onChangeText ={(value) => this.setState({text:value})}
                    value={this.state.text}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="Ingredients"
                    onChangeText ={(ingText) => this.setState({ingText})}
                    value={this.state.ingText}
                  />
                  <TextInput
                    placeholder="Steps"
                    onChangeText ={(stepsText) => this.setState({stepsText})}
                    value={this.state.stepsText}
                  />

              <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                  <Button onPress={() => {
                      this.vegeRef.update({title:this.state.text, ing:this.state.ingText, steps:this.state.stepsText});
                      this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                    }}
                      title="Save Recipe"
                  >
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                      onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}
                      title="Cancel"
                  >
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Firebase JSON

```
  "Vegetarian" : {
    "-L3RaWBQchF5rKmVtpNk" : {
      "ing" : "Aasaaaa",
      "steps" : "Aa",
      "title" : "Eeww"
    },
    "-L3WdmePSwkWNN4xB51M" : {
      "ing" : "This is good",
      "steps" : "Nice",
      "title" : "Salad"
    },
```

Comment: can you please attach the snapshot of your firebase node. It is better to know what is your node tree structure before saving and rather than creating different states for each value create an array to save value on basis of key

Comment: Hi, I have attached the firebase JSON node tree structure on above. Thank you for your responese :)

Answer (score 1):

Here I have change the method to update the firebase node. I am getting the firebase timestamp of each node along with the data from `vegref` and sending that firebase timestamp along with input to know exact node I wanst to update.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Button,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
    ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import firebase from './firebase';

export default class RecipeDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            editedCode:{},
            modalVisible: false
        }

        this.vegeRef = this.getRef().child('Vegetarian');
    }

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    getRef() {
        return firebase.database().ref();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        vegeRef.on('value', s => {
            this.setState({
                items: [...this.state.items, { ...s.val(), firebaseUrl: s.key }]
            })
        })
    }

    // handleCodeChange function is used to handle the changed text inside each text input 
    handleCodeChange = (newVal, itemIndex) => {
        let item = this.state.items[itemIndex]
        let newItem = Object.assign(item, { [key]: newVal })
        let oldItems = this.state.items
        oldItems[itemIndex] = newItem
        this.setState({
            items: oldItems,
            editedCode:newItem
        })
    }

    updateItems = () => {
        let object = this.state.editedCode
        e.preventDefault()
        vegeRef.child(object.firebaseUrl).once("value", function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.ref.update({
                text: object.text,
                ing: object.ing,
                steps: object.stepsText
            }, () => {
                console.log("record updated")
            })
        });
    }

    render() {

        let itemNodes = this.state.items.map ((item, itemIndex) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Add Recipes"
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.handleCodeChange(e.target.value, item.text)}
                        value={item.text}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Ingredients"
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.handleCodeChange(e.target.value, item.ingText)}
                        value={item.ingText}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Steps"
                        onChangeText={(e) => this.handleCodeChange(e.target.value, item.stepsText)}
                        value={item.stepsText}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        })


        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    animationType={'slide'}
                    onRequestClose={() => { }}
                >
                    <Text>Edit the details and Update.</Text>
                    {itemNodes}
                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                            <Button onPress={this.updateItems}
                                title="Save Recipe"
                            >
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}
                                title="Cancel"
                            >
                            </Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: componentDidMount() {
        vegeRef.on('value', s => {
            this.setState({
                items: [...this.state.items, { ...s.val(), firebaseUrl: s.key }]
            })
        })
    } 

I'm sorry that I don't understand this part, can you explain to me please

Comment: I have tried the code you given and i get an error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: vegeRef

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I still get an error showing Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value') when i try to key in value, and the TextInput is not showing the values retrieved from firebase.

Comment: I will work on it till then you just try to manipulate the code by understanding the logic. I have seen the firebase snapshot . I will change my code accordingly. just elaborate more on question how you actually wants to inert the node.

Comment: Truly thanks for your help :) yeah  I'm trying my best to understand the logic and trying it out too, for my question is, when users clicked on the recipe list, it will go to this page, and there is a key for that list pressed passed to this page as {this.props.key}, and I'm trying to use this key to specify the recipe details according to the recipe list selected, and then when user pressed the update button, the recipes details is showed on the TextInput inside the modal, so they can edit the details directly  at ther and update back to firebase. Hope you can understand my elaboration :)

Comment: @Himanshul, Hi, do you have any new solution for this? please help me. I have tried it the whole but still not working yet

Comment: I have edited the code now. But according to your comment your did not match with your requirement. You have to fetch the value on basis of `{this.props.key}` and then view the data in editable text input which can be updated by the user. Correct me If I am getting wrong

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried your code but it's not working, and I have another solution for part of it,  now I'm having a problem with the this.props._key with the database path, can you help me out? This is the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513200/how-to-set-this-props-key-into-the-firebase-database-reference-in-react-native