# How to set this.props.key into the Firebase database reference in react native

Tags: json, database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved the values from the other component and displayed in the TextInput for users to edit the values which are the (itemTitle: this.props.title, itemIng: this.props.ing, itemSteps: this.props.steps) and now 
I'm trying to update the values back to firebase after user pressed the button in modal. But I'm having a problem to get the firebase database reference, I'm able get the {this.props._key} from another component but when I write as a .child(itemKey) it's not working and shows "Can't find variable: itemKey" Does anyone has the similar problem?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Modal,
  TextInput,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions}from 'react-native-router-flux';

import firebase from './firebase';

const remote = 'http://l.rgbimg.com/cache1oCOq1/users/b/ba/ba1969/600/mxc1dae.jpg';

export default class RecipeDetails extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

      modalVisible: false,
      itemTitle: this.props.title,
      itemIng: this.props.ing,
      itemSteps: this.props.steps,
      itemKey: this.props._key.toString(),
    };

    this.vegeRef = this.getRef().child('Vegetarian').child(itemKey);
    this.fastRef = this.getRef().child('Fast Food');
    this.hpRef = this.getRef().child('Healthy');

  }


  setModalVisible(visible){
    this.setState({modalVisible:visible});
  }

  getRef(){
    return firebase.database().ref();
  }

  updateItem(){
    this.setModalVisible(true);
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Modal
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                animationType={'slide'}
                onRequestClose={() => {}}
            >
            <Text>Edit the details and Update.</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    value={this.state.itemTitle}
                    onChangeText ={(itemTitle) => this.setState({ itemTitle })}

                  />
                  <TextInput
                    value={this.state.itemIng}
                    onChangeText ={(itemIng) => this.setState({itemIng})}

                  />
                  <TextInput
                    value={this.state.itemSteps}
                    onChangeText ={(itemSteps) => this.setState({itemSteps})}

                  />

              <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                  <Button onPress={() => {
                      this.vegeRef.update({title:this.state.itemTitle, ing:this.state.itemIng, steps:this.state.itemSteps});
                      this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                    }}
                      title="Save Recipe"
                  >
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                      onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}
                      title="Cancel"
                  >
                  </Button>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Modal>


            <ImageBackground
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                paddingVertical: 35 

              }}
              source={{ uri: remote }}
            >
            <ScrollView style={styles.container2} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <Text style={styles.heading1}>
                  Ingredients
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.heading2}>
                  {this.props.ing}
                  {this.props._key}
                </Text>

                <Text style={styles.heading1}>
                  Steps
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.heading2}>
                  {this.props.steps}
                </Text>
            </ScrollView>
            </ImageBackground>

        <View style={styles.action}>
              <TouchableHighlight
                underlayColor='#24ce84'
                onPress={this.updateItem.bind(this)}
              >
                <Text style = {styles.actionText}>Update Recipe</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Firebase JSON format

```
 "Vegetarian" : {
    "-L3RaWBQchF5rKmVtpNk" : {
      "ing" : "Aasaaaa",
      "steps" : "Aa",
      "title" : "Eeww"
    },
    "-L3WdmePSwkWNN4xB51M" : {
      "ing" : "This is good",
      "steps" : "Nice",
      "title" : "Salad"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value ot itemKey to this.state.itemKey and that will not be inside constructor as your are initialising the states in constructor. Also whenever you are calling any function like you have called `update` to update the values. Try to use the update query of firebase inside a function and use that in `onPress` event of Button react element. Please check modified code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Button,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
    ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import firebase from './firebase';

const remote = 'http://l.rgbimg.com/cache1oCOq1/users/b/ba/ba1969/600/mxc1dae.jpg';

export default class RecipeDetails extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            modalVisible: false,
            itemTitle: this.props.title,
            itemIng: this.props.ing,
            itemSteps: this.props.steps,
            itemKey: this.props._key.toString(),
        };

        // this.vegeRef = this.getRef();
        this.fastRef = this.getRef().child('Fast Food');
        this.hpRef = this.getRef().child('Healthy');

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRef().child('Vegetarian').on('child_added', s => {
            if (s.exists()) {
                console.log(s.val()) // It will return the new updated object
                console.log(s.key) // It will return the timestamp key
                this.setState({
                    itemTitle: s.val().title,
                    itemIng: s.val().ing,
                    itemSteps: s.val().steps,
                })
            }
        })
    }

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    getVegRef = () => {
        this.getRef().child('Vegetarian').child(this.state.itemKey)
    }

    getRef = () => {
        return firebase.database().ref();
    }

    updateVeg = () => {
        this.getVegRef().update(
            {
                title: this.state.itemTitle,
                ing: this.state.itemIng,
                steps: this.state.itemSteps
            });
        this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
    }

    updateItem() {
        this.setModalVisible(true);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    animationType={'slide'}
                    onRequestClose={() => { }}
                >
                    <Text>Edit the details and Update.</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.itemTitle}
                        onChangeText={(itemTitle) => this.setState({ itemTitle })}

                    />
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.itemIng}
                        onChangeText={(itemIng) => this.setState({ itemIng })}

                    />
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.itemSteps}
                        onChangeText={(itemSteps) => this.setState({ itemSteps })}

                    />

                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                            <Button onPress={
                                this.updateVeg
                            }
                                title="Save Recipe"
                            >
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}
                                title="Cancel"
                            >
                            </Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>


                <ImageBackground
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        paddingVertical: 35

                    }}
                    source={{ uri: remote }}
                >
                    <ScrollView style={styles.container2} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <Text style={styles.heading1}>
                            Ingredients
                </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.heading2}>
                            {this.props.ing}
                            {this.props._key}
                        </Text>

                        <Text style={styles.heading1}>
                            Steps
                </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.heading2}>
                            {this.props.steps}
                        </Text>
                    </ScrollView>
                </ImageBackground>

                <View style={styles.action}>
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor='#24ce84'
                        onPress={this.updateItem.bind(this)}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.actionText}>Update Recipe</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it has been fixed but when i updated the values, the firebase data is updated but the `{this.props.ing}` and `{this.props.steps}` still remain the ori values, do you have any idea to refresh the current page, so these two values will be updated?
 
Besides, do you have any ideas how to write hasChild method for firebase? I wanted to run the update function only if the `getVegRef()`
 has `{this.props._key}` this child inside of it. I have tried it but it shows `{this.props.key}` is not an object.

Comment: yes for that Please update the snapshot of your firebase and print the value of `this.props.key` So that I will know what is the key your are using for firebase.

Comment: the firebase data is updated but the `{this.props.ing}` and `{this.props.steps}` still remain the ori values, do you have any idea to refresh the current page, so these two values will be updated?

Comment: the value of `{this.props.key}` is a random key passed from the  previous component. So I'm trying to use that as the child of `getVegRef()`

Comment: Please check the updated code for updating the vaue either you can fetch the value using `on("child_added")` inside `componentDidMount` function or you can set the value by getting input from your text box before updating the value. Since `this.props` is used as static value which cannot be changed use `this.setState` to set the new vlaues inside `updateVeg()` function. Please accept and upvote the answer before asking another question.

Comment: thank you for your response, it shows an error with  `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.getVegRef.on')`, any ideas ?

Comment: It shows an error with `undefined is not an object(evaluating'_this.getVegRef().update')` and in the TextInput part, when click the other list details from previous component, the TextInput still show the values of last updated instead of the details clicked. Any ideas to fix it ? Thanks :)